# Get Outreach Activity data from ORN via SOAP calls

Tags: soap, rightnow-crm

I use **Oracle RightNow** via **[SOAP API](http://documentation.custhelp.com/euf/assets/devdocs/may2017/Connect_Web_Services_for_SOAP/Default.htm)**.

Using `QueryCSV` option, I can get a lot of information (E.g.: about an incident `SELECT * FROM Incident WHERE ...`), but I don't know how to get information about **Outreach Activity**.

I saw on the [RightNow forum](http://communities.rightnow.com/posts/4302a1c52f) that I could get this kind of information from `ma_trans` table, but I don't know how to select data from this table.

> *Outreach Activity tab that should show data from the ma_trans table*

I tried different approaches, but I always get responses like this:

Request:

```
SELECT * FROM ma_trans
```

Response:

```
...
    <n0:RequestErrorFault xmlns:n0="urn:faults.ws.rightnow.com/v1_3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <n0:exceptionCode>INVALID_REQUEST</n0:exceptionCode>
       <n0:exceptionMessage>no such table: ma_trans</n0:exceptionMessage>
    </n0:RequestErrorFault>
...
```

or

Request:

```
SELECT Contact.ma_trans FROM Contact
```

Response:

```
...
    <n0:RequestErrorFault xmlns:n0="urn:faults.ws.rightnow.com/v1_3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <n0:exceptionCode>INVALID_REQUEST</n0:exceptionCode>
       <n0:exceptionMessage>Non-existent column: 'ma_trans'</n0:exceptionMessage>
    </n0:RequestErrorFault>
...
```

How can I get information about Outreach Activity and how can I get data from this `ma_trans` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ma_trans` table is not exposed through the Connect Object Model or ROQL.  `transactions` is exposed through ROQL, as well as some of the other "managed tables", which you can view in any of the documentation for services that expose connect APIs (i.e. the PHP, SOAP, REST, etc. APIs).

You could get this data by creating a report to query for the data that you need, and then use the runAnalyticsReport method to get data from the report.  But, since `ma_trans` can contain a lot of data, be sure that your report is filtered properly as to not extend beyond run time or data threshold limits.